# For the given dataset I am not able to compile and fit the placeholder. it results in an error

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, data-science

I have been asked to produce a CNN output for the given dataset. 
The error is 
`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (16, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0', which has shape '(?, 60, 11, 1)'`
The dataset is included below

```
Att1    Att2    Att3    Att4    Att5    Att6    Att7    Att8    Att9    Att10   Att11
1   0   1   0.9471  C   0   S   0.8561  0.002   0.004   1.8091
1   0   1   0.992   C   0   S   0.8648  0.002   0.003   1.861
1   0   1   1.0722  C   0   S   2.009   0.002   0.003   3.0876
1   0   1   0.994   C   0   S   0.8754  0.002   0.003   1.8744
1   0   1   1.0121  C   0   S   0.9275  0.002   0.003   1.9447
1   0   1   0.9825  C   0   S   0.9579  0.002   0.003   1.9455
1   0   1   0.7372  C   0   S   0.8699  0.002   0.003   1.6122
1   0   1   0.9533  C   0   S   0.8377  0.002   0.004   1.797
1   0   1   0.9813  C   0   S   0.8647  0.002   0.003   1.8511
1   0   1   0.9693  C   0   S   0.8664  0.001   0.003   1.8402
1   0.0005  1   0.9652  C   0   S   0.8625  0.002   0.003   1.8317
1   0   1   1.0564  C   0   S   0.8796  0.002   0.003   1.941
1   0   1   0.9562  C   0   S   0.8503  0.002   0.003   1.8115
1   0   1   0.9581  C   0   S   0.8491  0.002   0.003   1.8113
1   0   1   0.9919  C   0   S   0.9162  0.0015  0.025   1.9121
1   0   1   0.9443  C   0   S   0.8479  0.002   0.003   1.7973
1   0   1   0.7454  C   0   S   0.8722  0.002   0.003   1.6225
1   0   1   0.9979  C   0   S   1.0774  0.002   0.003   2.0803
1   0   1   0.7275  C   0   S   0.9696  0.0014  0.0025  1.7012
1   0   1   1.089   C   0   S   1.9643  0.0015  0.0025  3.0573
2   0.0005  1   0.9699  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.004   1.8268
2   0   1   0.7045  C   0   S   0   0.0015  0.0029  1.5466
2   0   1   0.9584  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.00298 1.8052
22  0   1   0.744   C   0   S   0   0.0015  0.0025  1.598
2   0   1   0.744   C   0   S   0   0.0015  0.0025  1.598
2   0   1   0.7379  C   0   S   0   0.0019  0.003   1.5926
2   0   1   0.756   C   0   S   0   0.0019  0.003   1.6523
2   0   1   0.737   C   0   S   0   0.002   0.0029  1.7028
2   0   1   0.707   C   0   S   0   0.0015  0.0025  4.249
2   0   1   0.7127  C   0   S   0   0.001   0.003   1.5867
2   0   1   0.7177  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.003   1.5921
2   0   1   0.7299  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.003   1.5706
2   0   1   0.7549  C   0   S   0   0.0014  0.003   1.5835
2   0   1   0.6954  C   0   S   0   0.0019  0.003   1.5239
2   0   1   0.7131  C   0   S   0   0.0019  0.003   1.5401
2   0   1   0.712   C   0   S   0   0.0014  0.0025  1.525
2   0   1   0.7074  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.003   1.5304
2   0   1   0.7382  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.0029  1.5704
2   0   1   0.7052  C   0   S   0   0.0019  0.003   1.5693
2   0   1   0.7178  C   0   S   0   0.002   0.003   1.5438
3   0   1   0.9599  C   0   S   1.2939  0.0015  0.003   2.2583
3   0   1   0.957   C   0   S   0   0.0019  0.003   0.9619
3   0   1   1.0089  C   0   S   0.9696  0.0015  0.0025  1.9825
3   0   1   0.7337  C   0   S   0.99    0.002   0.003   1.7287
3   0   1   0.7238  C   0   S   0.9761  0.001   0.003   1.7042
3   0   1   0.9554  C   0   S   0.9685  0.0019  0.003   1.9299
3   0   1   0.7128  C   0   S   0.821   0.002   0.003   1.539
3   0   1   0.7562  C   0   S   1.0262  0.0019  0.003   1.7875
3   0   1   0.7617  C   0   S   0.9947  0.002   0.004   1.7625
3   0   1   0.7543  C   0   S   0.9934  0.002   0.003   1.7527
3   0   1   0.7243  C   0   S   0.9709  0.002   0.003   1.7003
3   0   1   0.7157  C   0   S   1   0.002   0.003   1.7208
3   0   1   0.7075  C   0   S   0.9861  0.0015  0.0025  1.6977
3   0   1   0.7418  C   0   S   0.9477  0.0019  0.003   1.6946
3   0   1   0.701   C   0   S   0.9645  0.0015  0.0025  1.6695
3   0   1   0.7443  C   0   S   1.0016  0.002   0.003   1.751
3   0   1   0.7101  C   0   S   0.9661  0.002   0.003   1.6813
3   0   1   0.706   C   0   S   0.9734  0.002   0.003   1.6845
3   0   1   0.713   C   0   S   0.9791  0.0015  0.0025  1.6962
3   0   1   0.7085  C   0   S   0.9968  0.0015  0.0025  1.7104
```

My working is put below. The last part i.e the tf.Session() part is producing an error called "could not convert string to float: 'C' ". any help as why this error would help me understand a lot better.

Thank you in advance.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:/Users/ggmah/Desktop/HMM Data updated.xlsx")
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
dff = OneHotEncoder(df)
dfg = pd.get_dummies(df)
# df.head()
# dff
# dfg

o =list(df.columns.values)
label_dict = dict()
for i,value in enumerate(o):
    label_dict[i] = value
# label_dict
# len(label_dict)

training_iters = 220 
learning_rate = 0.002 
batch_size = 16
n_input = 59
n_classes = 11
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 60,11,1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
#     x: input var
#     W: weight fn
#     b: bias
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x) 

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],padding='SAME')


weights = {
    'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(3,3,1,32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,32,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(3,3,64,128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wd1': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(4*4*128,128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'out': tf.get_variable('W6', shape=(128,n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
}
biases = {
    'bc1': tf.get_variable('B0', shape=(32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc2': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc3': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bd1': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'out': tf.get_variable('B4', shape=(11), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
}



# from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
# data = input_data.read_data_sets('data/fashion',one_hot=True)
X = dfg[['Att1','Att2','Att3','Att4',
         'Att5_C', 
         'Att6',
         'Att7_S', 
         'Att8','Att9','Att10']]

Y = dfg[['Att11']]
train_X, test_X,train_y,test_y = train_test_split(X,Y,train_size=0.88,random_state=5)



def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  

    # here we call the conv2d function we had defined above and pass the input image x, weights wc1 and bias bc1.
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 14*14 matrix.
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    # here we call the conv2d function we had defined above and pass the input image x, weights wc2 and bias bc2.
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 7*7 matrix.
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 4*4.
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)


    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv3, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Output, class prediction
    # finally we multiply the fully connected layer with the weights and add a bias term. 
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out


pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

#Here you check whether the index of the maximum value of the predicted image is equal to the actual labelled image. and 
# both will be a column vector.
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

#calculate accuracy across all the given images and average them out. 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    train_accuracy = []
    test_accuracy = []
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./Output', sess.graph)
    for i in range(training_iters):
        for batch in range(len(train_X)//batch_size):
            batch_x = train_X[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(train_X))]
            batch_y = train_y[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(train_y))]    
            # Run optimization op (backprop).
                # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            opt = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})
        print("Iter " + str(i) + ", Loss= " + \
                      "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                      "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        print("Optimization Finished!")

        # Calculate accuracy for all 10000 mnist test images
        test_acc,valid_loss = sess.run([accuracy,cost], feed_dict={x: test_X,y : test_y})
        train_loss.append(loss)
        test_loss.append(valid_loss)
        train_accuracy.append(acc)
        test_accuracy.append(test_acc)
        print("Testing Accuracy:","{:.5f}".format(test_acc))
    summary_writer.close()
```

I am supposed to produce a graph showing the growth of the learning curve for various learning rates and varying input sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You encode your data using `dfg = pd.get_dummies(df)` but then use `df` to create `X` and `y`:

```
X = df[['Att1','Att2','Att3','Att4','Att5','Att6','Att7','Att8','Att9','Att10']]
Y = df[['Att11']]
```

Instead of using `dfg`:

```
X = dfg[['Att1','Att2','Att3','Att4',
         'Att5_C', # Note column name change
         'Att6',
         'Att7_S', # Note column name change
         'Att8','Att9','Att10']]

Y = dfg[['Att11']]
```

Note that `pd.get_dummies` will add a prefix to the names of any columns that are transformed, hence the need to specify `Att5_C` and `Att7_S` for `X`.

Comment: sir changing the above results in an error in tf.Session.run()                                           
             ```                                                                                                      ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (16, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_4:0', which has shape '(?, 60, 11, 1)'                                                                                             
  ```

Comment: As a pointer, you define the x `placeholder` to be `(None, 60, 11, 1)` which isn't compatible with your `batch_size` or `n_input`. However, this is an unrelated problem to the original question, so should really be a question of its own.

Comment: You are most welcome. I'm about to start work but if you post a separate question, send me a link in a comment here and if it's not answered by the time I get home I'll have a look.